# Question regarding Pandas Dataframes. Why are columns dropped?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I really like to understand why something does or does not work.

I am reading a bunch of data from an Excel file into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
 # Import the Excel file
self.df_ImportData = pd.read_excel(excel_file, usecols=vc.columns_to_read)
```

I then want to strip certain characters from entries from the 'Peoples Resource Name' column, so I use:

```
self.df_ImportData['People Resource Name'] = self.df_ImportData["People Resource Name"].str.rsplit(' (', n=1).str.get(0)
```

This works perfectly.

I was trying to perform temporary operations in non class data (local) data frames/variables.

I was originally reading the data into **df_Temp**.  But when I do that, and then perform the split on df_ImportData[...], I only get the 'People Resource Name' column in this new DataFrame.

```
 # Import the Excel file
df_Temp = pd.read_excel(excel_file, usecols=vc.columns_to_read)

self.df_ImportData['People Resource Name'] = df_Temp["People Resource Name"].str.rsplit(' (', n=1).str.get(0)
```

But, if I do the operations directly on the class data frame I get the whole data frame.  Why is that?

Comment: when do you assign the full dataframe to `self.df_ImportData` if you don't do it in your read step? From the code you've shared it looks like the columns aren't dropped - you never assign them.

Comment: It's done in the excelread function of Pandas.  df_Temp contains all of the columns and rows.

Comment: Is self.df_ImportData initialised elsewhere? If not it will error when you try and assign the column. But if you initialise it as an empty dataframe (`self.df_ImportData = pd.DataFrame()`) then your assign statement will assign the `People Resource Name` column. But you don't assign the other columns anywhere.

Comment: Everything is read into df_Temp from the excelread function in Pandas.  The entire dataframe is full of all the data in the Excel file.  The issue is when I assign it to the class data frame, only the 'filtered' column is put into the class frame.